# How to get absolute current time for LIVE dash stream from chromecast?

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I need to know the chromecast current position when playing a live dash stream.
For testing I am using [this](https://akamaibroadcasteruseast.akamaized.net/cmaf/live/657078/akasource/out.mpd) akamai stream.

I tried to use [RemoteMediaClient.getApproximateStreamPosition()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/RemoteMediaClient#getApproximateStreamPosition()) but it only gives me the time since the stream was loaded by chromecast. It works well for VOD.

I then created a simple WebReceiver application to see if would be possible to have some information about the current position. From [PlayerManager](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver/cast.framework.PlayerManager) it is possible to call `getCurrentTimeSec` together with `getAbsoluteTimeForMediaTime` to obtain the absolute position in seconds.

However when I compare the value from

```
PlayerManager.getAbsoluteTimeForMediaTime(PlayerManager.getCurrentTimeSec())
```

with what I see on chromecast the value is offset (advanced) by around 3 seconds. I also tried another stream and the offset was around 5 seconds.

So my question is how can I know the chromecast's correct absolute current position for live streams?